# Core Data bound NSCollectionView or NSTableView with one item static?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller, nscollectionview

Is it possible to have a `NSCollectionView` bound to a core data model (by `NSArrayController`) and having the first item not to show the first item of `NSArrayContoller` but a custom view (`NSButton`)?

(The second item of the `NSCollectionView` would then dislpay the `NSArrayController`'s first item.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that it is possible, but I am not sure that it is necessary.

If that first item is unrelated to the collection (at least in terms of display) why even include it in the collection view? You can make it a separate view styled to fit in with the collection view and then use the collection view as intended.

Comment: good idea, but it should be a multi-row, multi-column collection view. i'd like to set the first (top left) item of that grid to be static..

Comment: In that case I think that there is no easy way to do what you want. I would start by looking at NSCollectionView to see if you could subclass it to insert your button before the items in your model, or subclassing NSArrayController to return a dummy object for index 0. You might have to end up doing a combination of both. Of course, it might be better to find a different UI strategy.

Comment: Same problem here. I'd like to include a "add item" item as the first view in the collection. I tried overriding [NSArrayController arrangeObjects:id] inserting my object at the beginning. Almost works. Only problem is that the item is not shown when the array is empty...